# Ansible Tower with dynamic inventory issue: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable"

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-inventory

I use AWS EC2 dynamic inventory in my Ansible Tower and my instances are tagged with their environment. For example:

Key: Environment

Value: NonProd

This creates a group tag_Environment_NonProd which contains tagged hosts. Now I want to "set_fact" using this group:

```
- name: Determine nodes to join in NonProd
  hosts: tag_Group_Elasticsearch
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Setting nodes IPs 
    set_fact:
      NonProd_list: "{{ groups['tag_Environment_NonProd'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | list }}"
```

I spin up NonProd tagged instances only from time to time so tag_Environment_NonProd group is not available all the time and that is the reason I am facing this issue.

I tried with the following conditionals but it didn't help:

when: tag_Environment_NonProd is defined

when: ('tag_Environment_NonProd' in group_names)

I also tried to ignore_error but apparently it also doesn't work with "undefined variable".

Anybody has an idea how to resolve this?

Many thanks.

Dragan

Answer (score 0):

The global approach is to make sure you always have a value when the variable is not defined. Use the [`default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) for that.

The following will set `NonProd_list` to an empty list when the group does not exists (or is empty). This way you fix you current error and you don't have to test later that the set var exists.

```
  - name: Setting nodes IPs 
    set_fact:
      NonProd_list: >-
        {{ 
          groups['tag_Environment_NonProd']
          | default([])
          | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host'])
          | list
        }}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator 
I tried to add 'default' filter as you advised but no luck...


```"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'tag_Environment_NonProd'```

Comment: I also tried to use the default value "default(5, true)" but it didn't work